# JDeveloper Cannot run application due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I have a simple Fusion Web Application program that I could run my simple application on the weblogic server before, but now when I try to run the JSF page I get these errors:

```
Deployment cancelled.
----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
 Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)
#### Cannot run application MyFirstApplication due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: check in the messages panel of jdev

Comment: Same error here - I suspect a permissions problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the steps of running an application on weblogic server (or any other java server) consists of the following 4 steps:

1. Compilation and building
2. Starting the server
3. Deploying the fusion web application
4. Running the application

Errors could happen in any of the steps, and would cause obstacles to move to the next steps.
Your problem seems to be in the deployment phase, so the next step which is the running of the application is stopped from being executed.

It is worth to mention that your savior is the logs.
So you need to look into the deployment logs where it would clearly show the fault and the exception from not being deployed.

Comment: [Running application sumar2 on IntegratedWebLogicServer...] 
[05:22:46 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[05:22:46 PM] Target platform is  (Weblogic 12.x).
[05:22:46 PM] Running dependency analysis...
[05:22:46 PM] Deploying profile...
[05:22:47 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[05:22:47 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[05:22:47 PM] Unable to package module
[05:22:47 PM] null
#### Cannot run application sumar2 due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer.
[05:22:47 PM] Cancel requested
[Application sumar2 stopped and undeployed from IntegratedWebLogicServer]

Comment: comment on your version of jdeveloper and weblogic. The actual error doesn't show here, can you point it out as well?

Comment: Hi here i upload the pics https://thedevnote.blogspot.mx/2017/07/cant-run-my-soa-aplication-with.html

Comment: Try using latest version of jdeveloper, or apply patches to correct bugs or open up the composite.xml in design mode. Initiate a jar build or deployment again and the process will go through successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

1. Close Jdeveloper application.
2. Delete systemXX.x.x.x.x directory.
3. Restart Jdeveloper and integrated weblogic server.

I also faced the same issue but after deleting system directory, my server started successfully.

Comment: Hey, could you please transform your listing ( 1), 2), 3) ) into a List using the Editor so anyone can see the point of your answer directly and clear? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it.
Please Follow These Steps :

1. Right Click On The Model ;
2. Project Properties...
3. Select In Left Page; "JAVA EE Application"
4. Insert In Java Web Application Name:  XXXApplication-XXXModel-webapp (XXX is Name Of Project )
5. Insert Into Java EE Webcontent Root : XXXApplication-XXXModel-context-root

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm on JDeveloper 11g Release 2.

The following worked for me:

1. At the application menu bar - click on **Run** option.
2. Click on **Start Server Instance** - IntegratedWebLogicServer (in my case)
3. Wait for Server to fully start.
4. Locate **Projects** box/section/tree structure, locate your project name. Right Click.
5. Select **Deploy**, (create a deployment profile if required), to open the deployment wizard.
6. In the deployment wizard, select **Deploy to Application Server**, click Next.
7. In my case, I saw the IntegratedWebLogicServer instance in the following list, I selected it, and continue/finish with the deployment.

I strongly believe this is related to permissions.

I was able to run and deploy my applications to the default Web Logic server until I had more restrictions in my Windows machine - for example I was no longer a local administrator.

Hope this helps.